# Can we run thin client to connect to Linux (Suse or Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opensuse, thin-client

Not sure where to ask such questions, so guide me on that!

I am looking to have several thin clients to use same server (system), the work involved is mostly office and browsing related works - that can be done using Linux as it involves doing most work on browsers based softwares and some using Open Office / Libre office.

Which Linux OS is good to be used as server (main system) for the same? I have earlier used Linux Suse and Ubuntu and comfortable using the same, However, any recommendations are good to help me proceed further with this.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you're the one who will be setting it up, and you're only asking about which distro to use for the *server.*)

Most distros are suitable for a simple server, so I'd recommend using the server flavour (if any) of **a distro you're familiar with.** There really isn't much to it - you'll need to do at least some rough scaling of the amount of RAM and disk + speed of CPU/network, but that's another subject.

Comment: Is there any tutorial where you can point me to learn more about it

Comment: "It" is very unclear as it stands. You might want to add other, more specific questions on this and other sites to deal with issues as they come up.